# JavaFX TreeTableView is slow when expand the nodes?

Tags: java, database, javafx

we use a TreeTabelView to view products with subproducts. But when we click on the triangle to expand a node, than there is a very big delay (about 1000 ms).

Here is the code:

```
package controller;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TreeItemPropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import loginPackage.DBConnection;
import model.Product;
import model.ProductType;

import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class ShowSetsController implements Initializable{
    @FXML
    private TreeTableView TTVShowSets;
    @FXML
    private TreeTableColumn tcShowSetsProductName, tcShowSetsDescription;
    @FXML
    private TextField tfSearch;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        TTVShowSets.setVisible(true);
        tcShowSetsProductName.setCellValueFactory(new TreeItemPropertyValueFactory<>("productTypeName"));
        tcShowSetsDescription.setCellValueFactory(new TreeItemPropertyValueFactory<>("productTypeDescription"));

        List<Product> setHeaders = null;
        try {
            setHeaders = DBConnection.getInstance().getHighestSetHeaders();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        TTVShowSets.setRoot(null);
        TreeItem<Product> root = new TreeItem<>(new Product(-1,null,null,null, null, null));
        for (int i = 0; i < setHeaders.size(); i++){
            TreeItem<Product> cache = new TreeItem<>(setHeaders.get(i));
            try {
                this.printSetsTree(setHeaders.get(i), cache);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            root.getChildren().add(cache);
        }
        TTVShowSets.setShowRoot(false);
        TTVShowSets.setRoot(root);
    }

    public void printSetsTree(Product head, TreeItem<Product> father) throws SQLException {
        List<Product> listOfChildren = DBConnection.getInstance().getProductsChildrenByProductID(head);
        for(int i = 0; i < listOfChildren.size(); i++) {
            listOfChildren.get(i).setIsChild(true);
            listOfChildren.get(i).setSelected(null);
            TreeItem<Product> child = new TreeItem<>(listOfChildren.get(i));
            father.getChildren().add(child);
            Product childProduct = listOfChildren.get(i);
            printSetsTree(childProduct,child);
        }
    }
    @FXML
    private  void serachProduct(KeyEvent event) throws SQLException {
        TTVShowSets.setVisible(true);
        TTVShowSets.setRoot(null);
        KeyCode keycode = event.getCode();
        String search = tfSearch.getText();
        if(keycode == KeyCode.BACK_SPACE && search.length() > 0){
            search = search.substring(0,search.length()-1);
        }
        else search += event.getText();

        TreeItem<Product> root = new TreeItem<>(new Product(-1, null, null, null, null, null)); //empty root element
        List<Product> listHeaders = DBConnection.getInstance().getHighestSetHeaders();
        for (Product listHeader : listHeaders){
            TreeItem<Product> parent = new TreeItem<>(listHeader);
            List<Product> childs = DBConnection.getInstance().getProductsByProductTypeIdWhichAraNotInaSet(listHeader.getProducttypeID());
            for(Product child : childs){
                if (listHeader.getProductTypeName().toLowerCase().contains(search.toLowerCase())){
                    child.setIsChild(true);
                    TreeItem<Product> cache = new TreeItem<>(child);
                    printSetsTree(child, cache);
                    parent.getChildren().add(cache);
                }
            }
            if (parent.getChildren().size() > 0 && listHeader.getProductTypeName().toLowerCase().contains(search.toLowerCase())){
                root.getChildren().add(parent);
            }
            else TTVShowSets.setVisible(false);
        }
        TTVShowSets.setShowRoot(false);
        TTVShowSets.setRoot(root);
    }
    @FXML
    public void refreshTTV(){
        TTVShowSets.refresh();
    }
}
```

Maybe the implementation is false or the Database request are too slow, but we don't think that that is the reason because the TreeTableView is loaded with all nodes by initializing the pane? Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: How is `Product` implemented? Consider providing a [mcve].

Comment: You may also be affected by this bug: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8166956

Comment: Reflection is slow.  Consider writing your own cell value factories, for example `tcShowSetsProductName.setCellValueFactory(f -> f.getValue().productTypeNameProperty());`.  If your model classes aren’t based on JavaFX bean properties (like they should be), wrap them: `tcShowSetsProductName.setCellValueFactory(f -> new SimpleStringProperty(f.getValue().getProductTypeName()));`

Comment: Thank you for your help!